# DownloadError: ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, discord, youtube-dl

I ran into a problem when I used heroku

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe

*I am pretty sure that my code is fine because I ran it using my laptop, with ffmpeg, ffprobe and youtube-dl installed.*

- I installed the buildpack of ffmpeg and youtube-dl in heroku https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git, but I couldnt play songs using my bot.
- I created a link to my Github account in order to provide the source code, I gave the procfile and requirements and all of them are correct, since I use the same venv
- I've searched in help section of heroku and stack overflow for help, but I couldnt find anything valid as they all tell in detail about local installations

Could someone please look into it and find the solution to this problem?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Try watching this [video](https://youtu.be/u6o1yUUdc54). I used it to set up my music bot on Heroku, and it works perfectly for me.